# Eclipse doesn't start in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ide, m2e

I have a problem trying to launch Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04. Splash picture pops up, then blinks, turns white - and nothing happens until kingdom come.
I have tried Luna, Kepler and 3.8 (from Ubuntu repository). EE and SE editions - both the same. I have also tried to launch them with different (oracle) vm - 1.7 and 1.8. 
And yes, I have tried the `-clean` and simple workspace removal.

This is the only thing it says in console:

> org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the
>   state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location
>   is initialized.

Java VM works fine - I can launch (for example) IDEA or `java\javac` commands.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1) Remove **.snap** from:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<project>\.markers.snap
```

If you can't find it manually try this:

```
find /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects -name "*.snap" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: I have already tried all this stuff, even workspace full removal.

Comment: By the way, do you have two monitors?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how this fact is connected to my question.

Comment: Somewhere i read that one blank windows was showed in one screen, and the workspace selector was in the other one.

Comment: Holy cow, you're a genious! I just re-downloaded eclipse (wanted to give it 1 more chance) and after all my manipulations it STARTED on 2nd screen (which is my TV). Well, you know, workspace blabla thing.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem but it's the first time I launch eclipse on Ubuntu and I haven't set workspace directory yet, and I don't another monitor.

Comment: @Bugdaily You should start another thread, with your info attached.

Comment: I had the same problem with two monitors :) Thanks!

Comment: @Thrasher How can I ever thank you? I was being a smartass, and connected my monitor to my mac and my linux, so that I could plug/unplug and use it with both as I pleased. Turns out when I was using it with the mac it was still connected to the linux, and the workspace launcher was on the other screen while hidden.  Moral - Use monitors smartly.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is already here, but it's in the comments. So I re-post it as answer:
**check your 2nd screen**. Workspace dialogue may be there.

Answer (score 0):

It Generally happen when eclipse is closed unexpectedly.
Heres things you can do.!
1)Save and Delete .metadata from workspace folder.
2) Try Re-installing Eclipse.

This solution worked for me. :)

Comment: Or if you are on Ubuntu Try delete .eclipse from user folder will definitely remove any eclipse related error.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any pending changes and have pushed your project already on your repo, you can also try deleting the project folder where eclipse opens a project path automatically.

When you run eclipse again, it will work again.

Unfortunately, deleting metadata didnt work for me. Also I don't have any extra monitor so deleting my project folder was my last resort.