# Eclipse not getting Launched without showing any error tried eveything

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse is not working. Every time I open my eclipse its showing the splash screen  for 1 sec and then getting closed. I downloaded fresh eclipse i downloaded the new Oxygen but then also its getting closed.
Currently I am using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  and if I install any other version of eclipse its working !!
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, java version "1.8.0_131" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Other actions that I made:

1. I have deleted the .metadata folder.
2. I have reinstalled java.
3. I have edited the eclipse.ini file adding clean changing the memory size.
4. I am facing the same issue in neon ,mars and every eclipse IDE version!!

   Previously I was using ubuntu 16.04 then because of eclipse issue I downgraded it to 14.04 but still the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you trying to start? What is the outout of `java -version`?

Comment: Please state your operating system, OS type (32 or 64bit) and the JDK version you use.

Comment: Try to call Eclipse from command-line (call "eclipse.exe" from cmd-console
in case of Windows, or call "eclipse" from the shell in case of Linux etc).
You should see a lengthy error output, helping you to see what went wrong.

Comment: @kerner1000 - Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and my java version is java version "1.8.0_131"

Comment: @Zerthimon - I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) and the JDK version is 1.8

Comment: @ThomasFritsch org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Segmentation fault (core dumped) -This is the errror i am getting !!

Comment: ok @VivekSharma . It would be better you edit your question and put all these info (of your last 3 comments) there.

Comment: Google for "*The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized*". Then you will find some Eclipse bug reports and Stackoverflow questions, especially [Eclipse doesn't start in Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726191/eclipse-doesnt-start-in-ubuntu-14-04). May be the accepted answer there can help you.

Comment: Hey i tried everthing but i am not getting the exact solution for this !!

Comment: @VivekSharma JDK version 1.8 is for Java Standard Edition. What Java Enterprise Edition SDK have you installed?

Comment: @Zerthimon  java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: @VivekSharma I deleted my answer and modified/updated your post according to your comments, in order to help out solving this problem.